# Tricky SQL select

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, join

I have a message table, this table contains the following columns :

```
id | fromUserId | toUserId | sentDate | readDate | message | subject | fromUserDeleted(bit) | toUserDeleted(bit)
```

Now I need to select first message within every conversionen no mather if its from or to the current user. What makes it more complex is that I need to exclude messages that are deleted by the current user, so if the message is from current user then the fromUserDeleted have to be 0 if the message is from another user then toUserDeleted needs to be 0.

I know that there already are a lot of examples on how to select first post within groups but this is a bit more complex. The current user might be in toUserId or in fromUserId and the same goes for the deleted column.

This is what I have tried :

```
SELECT 
    m1.*, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM mail m3 WHERE m3.fromUserId=m1.fromUserId AND m3.toUserId=m1.toUserId AND m3.toUserDeleted = 0) as messageCount, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM mail m4 WHERE m4.toUserId=15 AND m4.readDate is null AND m4.toUserDeleted=0) as messagesNotRead 
FROM 
    mail m1 
LEFT JOIN mail m2 ON 
    ((m1.fromUserId = m2.fromUserId) and
    m2.)
WHERE 
    m2.id IS NULL AND 
    (m1.toUserId = 15 OR m1.fromUserId = 15) 
ORDER BY 
    m1.sentDate DESC;
```

And :

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    mail m1
WHERE
    ((m1.fromUserId = 15 AND m1.fromUserDeleted=0) OR (m1.toUserId = 15 AND m1.toUserDeleted=0)) AND
    m1.id = (SELECT m2.id FROM mail m2 WHERE m2.fromUserId = 15 OR m2.toUserId = 15 OR m2.fromUserId = m1.fromUserId OR m2.fromUserId = m1.toUserId OR m2.toUserId = m1.fromUserId OR m2.toUserId = m1.toUserId order By m2.sentDate desc limit 0,1)
Order by m1.sentDate DESC
```

None of these will do what I need. Pleas help!

It´s okay if a stored procedure needs to be created.

**IMPORTANT : This i MySQL**

EDIT 1:

Pleas see this for example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a2ef/3

Comment: Can you prepare an sql fiddle with test data and database structure? Also include an ideal result of what you want to get for that data. Better, if it was minimal, including all the possible cases.

Comment: only SendDate matters and readDate doesn't matter for the query?

Comment: @Rajesh readData most be in the select but it does not mather for the select logic.

Comment: What constitutes a "message".  If your ID column is auto-increment, and the message is probably the body and changes between from/to recipients, what identifies that message ID sequence 5 is a response from original message ID 2.  Is the subject changeable like it can be with email via Fwd and Reply?  That would break a commonality on that.

Comment: @DRapp, not really sure what you mean. But 2 messages do not link to each other in any way. Yes they might have the same toUserId and fromUserId (and in most cases its switched) but other then that they do not really have anything incommon.

Comment: @user4035, I hav tried to get a working fiddle, se my Edit1 but it does not work? I get Schema Creation Failed: INSERT command denied to user 'X'@'www' for table 'mail':

Comment: I have now added a link to a example! See Edit 1

Comment: @Banshee Seems, that something is wrong with sqlfiddle - it doesn't load the site for me. I'll look later.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback.  Hopefully this will address your need:

```
DECLARE @UserID INT
SELECT @UserID = 15

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT UserID, ConversationWithUserID, sentDate, readDate, [message], [subject], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ConversationWithUserID ORDER BY sentDate ASC) AS MessageOrder
    FROM (
        SELECT id, fromUserId AS UserID, toUserId AS ConversationWithUserID, sentDate, readDate, [message], [subject]
        FROM dbo.mail
        WHERE fromUserID = @UserID AND fromUserDeleted = 0
        UNION
        SELECT id, toUserId AS UserID, fromUserId AS ConversationWithUserID, sentDate, readDate, [message], [subject]
        FROM dbo.mail
        WHERE toUserId = @UserID AND toUserDeleted = 0
    ) x
) y
WHERE MessageOrder = 1
ORDER BY y.UserID, y.ConversationWithUserID
```

Comment: This will select all of the messages that the current user is involved in and that is not deleted by him/she. What I need is a list of the last mail from every conversation to/from all of the users. So between current user an user A we should only get the latest message back even if thay had 100 messages. And the same goes for current user and user B.

Comment: So how does one determine a conversation?  Do we assume that all messages back and forth are one conversation?

Comment: Yes a conversation is all messages where current user it toUserId or fromUserId.

Answer (score 0):

DOING UNPIVOT to get fromUSerId, toUserId under same column so that we can pick correct userId based on the sentDate.

```
SELECT T.*

FROM
(
    SELECT *,

           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY userVal ORDER BY sentDate DESC) as seq
    FROM
    (SELECT 
            *

     FROM msg
     WHERE (fromUserId = @userID AND fromUserDeleted = 0 ) 
           OR  (toUserId = @UserID AND toUserDeleted = 0)

    )p
    unpivot
    ( userVal for UserId in ( fromUserId, toUserId)
    )as unpvt
) T
WHERE seq =1
```

Comment: This is a bit more advanced then Im use to. I have tried the script(with correct userId) but gets syntax problems near : '( PARTITION BY userVal ORDER BY sentDate DESC) as seq     FROM     (SELECT      '

Comment: I used MS SQL, is your RDBMS is mysql?

Comment: Yes, sorry, its MySQL, I hade one of the MySQL tags but I should of course have mentioned it in my post as well.